# Homeomorphism between two subspaces

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X_1, X_2$ be subspaces given by $X_1 = (0,1) \cup (3,4)$ and $X_2 = (0,1)\cup(1,2)$. Are the subspaces homeomorphic?

I basically tried proving the contrapositive, but that made it even more difficult so I tried constructing something like, $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x &x\in(0,1) \\ 
 x-2& x\in(3,4)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

where $f: X_1 \to X_2$.

This is certainly 1-1 and onto (on the separate open intervals at least, but not on the real numbers). I guess it remains to show that this is continuous, but I honestly don't think showing any given open set, show that the pre image is open direction is good, and I don't think epsilon-delta is good when my space is disconnected like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remark that the spaces are disconnected is the key. By definition of disconnected we can restrict ourselves to open sets that are wholly contained in a single component, hence it suffices to show that we can pair the components into homeomorphic pairs, such as $(0,1)\to(0,1)$ and $(1,2)\to (3,4)$.

To see this in a very general and abstract context, consider this situation: Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, and $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ with $U_i$ open and pairwise disjoint. Let $f_i\colon U_i\to Y$ be continuous functions. Then we can define a map $f\colon X\to Y$,
by $f(x)=f_i(x)$ where $x\in U_i$.
Note that this is a map on $X$ and is well-defined because for each $x\in X$ there is one and only one $i\in I$ with $x\in U_i$. For any open set $W\subseteq Y$, we have $f^{-1}(W)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f_i^{-1}(W)$, which is the union of open sets, hence open. We conclude that $f$ is continuous.
This way we have a natural identification
$$\mathcal C(X,Y) \leftrightarrow\prod_{i\in I}\mathcal C(U_i,Y)$$
Now if also $Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$ wit $V_i$ open and pairwise disjoint and we have homeomorphisms $h_i\colon U_i\stackrel \approx\to V_i$, then $(h_i)_{i\in I}\in\prod \mathcal C(U_i,V_i)\subseteq \prod \mathcal C(U_i,Y)\cong \mathcal C(X,Y)$ and $(h_i^{-1})_{i\in I}\in\prod \mathcal C(V_i,U_i)\subseteq \prod \mathcal C(V_i,X)\cong \mathcal C(Y,X)$ give us a pair of continuous maps that are inverse of each other, i.e. $X\approx Y$.

Comment: Wait, how does this say $f$ is continuous? I assume that's what you meant when you say "airing the components"? Or did I miss something form this answer…?

Comment: I think there are typos there. *pair* the components *into* homeomorphic pairs....

Comment: I still don't know how this is sufficient.